# how to assign bulk profile to users in django

Tags: django, django-models

Am creating a custom command
And this command I want to add user profile to all the users who are company
So did this

```
companys =  Users.objects.filter(is_company=True)
```

Already I have created the users without assigning a profile to each of them
Now I I want to use a for loop to loop over each of the users and create a profile for that user
But the challenge now is am getting a `UNIQUE CONSTRAINTS FAILED`

I get stuck on the first user

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from accounts import models as accounts
from company import models as company

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        return super(Command, self).add_arguments(parser)

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        users = User.objects.all().filter(is_company=True)
        seen = set()
        for com_users in users:
            print(com_users)
            for company_detail in open('filenames/company_name.txt', 'r'):
                country = generate_countrys()
                name_email_tagline_address = company_detail.split('-')
                name = name_email_tagline_address[0]
                tagline = name_email_tagline_address[1]
                address = name_email_tagline_address[2]
                user = com_users
                department = generate_department()
                account_type = generate_account_type()
                date_added = generate_date_added()

                company_to_save = company.CompanyProfile.objects.create(
                    user=user, name=name, tagline=tagline, account_type=account_type, country=country,
                    joined_date=date_added, address=address, confirmed=True, department=department
                )
                company_to_save.save()
                seen.add(users)

        self.stdout.write(self.style.SUCCESS('Jobs Generated Successfully...'))
```

Is there a way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

User user model to create user and the create new model which contains user profile information linked to 'User' using foreign Key ..
Simple

Comment: i have already created the users all i want to do now is to assign profile the them

Comment: Create new Model Profile: Which contains additional user details and link it to User model using                                                                
                                                                       
''User = models.ForeignKey(User,null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)''                                                                                         
                                                                   
##Here  User is model name to which foreign key is used to establish link##